# Неверно выводит SUM mysql

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в данном запросе выводит 2500 а не 5000.

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM products WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id_product from order_products WHERE id_order=1)
```

```
products table
id | price
1  | 2500
```

```
order_products table
id | id_order |id_product 
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что надо учить нормальные джойны. А подзапросы - это такие джойны для бедных.

Здесь получается запрос

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM products WHERE id IN (1,1)
```

который на самом деле синтаксический сахар для запроса

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM products WHERE id=1 OR id=1
```

который возвращает 1 строчку

А нужен запрос, который возвращает 2 строчки. И это сделает как раз обычный простой джойн

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM order_products op, products p 
WHERE p.id=op.id_product and id_order=1
```